# Service to delete entries in SQLite db that is older than x days

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite

I have a `Service` which will clean up some files, and execute some SQL queries. This specific SQL query should delete entries which is older than x days. My method to do so, is this:

```
public boolean deleteOldCases(int days) {

        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CASES + " WHERE " + DATE +  " <= date('now','-" + days + " day')";
        Log.d("Delete Query: ", deleteQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        db.rawQuery(deleteQuery, null);
        db.close();

        return true;
    }
```

When am adding entries to my database, I do it like this:

```
public void addCase(Case c) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, c.getCaseNumber());
        values.put(STATUS, "");

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CASES, null, values);

        db.execSQL("Update " + TABLE_CASES + " Set " + DATE + "=datetime() where " + KEY_ID + "= '" + c.getCaseNumber() + "';" );

        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }
```

This method is called from my service, and I can verify by logging that this method is called. All of these data is displayed to the user in a ListView, which obviously works. But the old entries are not deleted at all..

I suspect that it's because I save the case with the `date = datetime()` and trying to remove it with `<=date('now', '-1 day')`

Can someone see what am doing wrong?

Comment: Comparing `datetime()` and `date()` results should work but isn't a "clean" solution. I would recommend to use java classes `Calendar` and especially `GregorianCalendar` with methods `getTimeInMillis()` and `setTimeInMillis()` to store the time as long integers in the database

Answer (score 0):

Use `rawQuery()`only for real queries (SQL-statements starting with "SELECT" keyword). Use `execSql()` instead.

Comment: I will try that, but want do you mean with real queries? Should also mentioned that this didn't do it.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Real queries start with "select" (answer edited)

Comment: Thanks, btw I didn't downvote your answer, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Selvin This is only written for `execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` but for `execSQL (String sql)` it is only discouraged and in pratice I'm using `execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` in my app without problems